# Failed verification of login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to verify my users who log into the system. I have used hashed passwords to store the passwords. When I try to verify the users, I get an error as follows:

```
strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I have searched various ways of solving this issue but I can't find a way.

Here is my code.

**controller.php**

```
public function logs_in(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');


    $hashedPassword = DB::select('select password from users where email = ?', [$email]);


    if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword)){
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 'Invalid 
        credentials entered');
    }
}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Your database query is wrong

Comment: What table is the passwords stored in... Users?

Comment: @Option I have run that query in mysql and it gives me the desired output. However, I am not able to compare what has been input with what is in the database. Yes the passwords are stored in the users table

Comment: Trust me, it won't work. Try: `$hashedPassword = User::where('email', $email)->first();` - providing password is in users table....

Comment: How am I getting the value of the password using that statement as only the email is being passed  @Option

Comment: You can run `$hashedPassword->password` to fetch specific things. `dd($hashedPassword)` will show you your available options. By default it'll select all from Users where the email = email you don't have to specify `SELECT`

Comment: Thanks man. @Option. I found my error. I was using a different way. It has worked for me

Comment: No problem at all. I have added an answer in for you but tidied the code up somewhat for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function logs_in(Request $request)
{
    $hashedPassword = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();


    if (Hash::check($request->get('password') == $hashedPassword->password))
    {
        // Yay it worked!
    } else {
        // You Borked it... Try again...
    }
}
```

You don't have to run a `select password` within the query as by default it'll select all. You HAVE to always run either `->get()` or `->first()` at the end of your query though. ->get() means you can use arrays so things like `$hashedPassword['password']` and `first()` being `$hashedPassword->password`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `first()` with `collect()` because your query return array

```
    $hashedPassword = collect(DB::select('select password from users where email = ?', [$email]))->first();
```

Secondly, you have to

```
if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword->password)){
    $request->session()->put('success');
    return redirect()->route('admin');
}
```

**OR**

```
DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->first();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It gives me the following error : Call to a member function first() on array

Comment: @jptl431 I have udpated the answer have look

Answer (score 0):

```
public function logs_in(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');


    $hashedPassword = collect(DB::select('select password from users where email = ?', [$email]))->first();


    if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword)){
      if (Hash::check($request->get('password') == $hashedPassword->password)){
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('admin');
      } else {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 'Invalid 
        credentials entered');
      }

    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 'Invalid 
        credentials entered');
    }
}
```

here email should be unique, so there will be only one email for one user. so use ->first() here.